# Cycle Through Array to Change Players PowerPoint VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a macro to cycle between three players on a game that I am making on PowerPoint. However, when I run the code, it changes once and and gets stuck. It won't cycle through the array. In the code I plan to change the color of the shape containing the player's name as well as show transparent gray buttons over the other players' boxes so that they can't adjust their scores. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SwitchPlayers()
   Dim oSl As Slide
   Dim RGB As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim myTurn() As Integer
   ReDim myTurn(2)  '0, 1, 2... 3 compartments

      Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
    
    
    
      For i = 0 To 2
      myTurn(i) = i + 1
    
    
      If myTurn(i) = 0 Then
          oSl.Shapes("T1NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2NB", "T3NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2+1G", "T2-1G", "T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = True
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G")).Visible = False
      ElseIf myTurn(i) = 1 Then
          oSl.Shapes("T2NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1NB", "T3NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G", "T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = True
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2+1G", "T2-1G")).Visible = False
      ElseIf myTurn(i) = 2 Then
          oSl.Shapes("T3NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1NB", "T2NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G", "T2+1G", "T2-1G")).Visible = True
          oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = False
      End If
        
      Next i
        
 End Sub
```

Comment: Each time you call the subroutine, you fill the myarray with the same numbers starting at 0, so each time it runs, it'll have the same effect. As a starting point, consider declaring Static lLastRun as Long and using that as the Case Selector. Set it to zero to start, increment it each time the sub gets called but if it's > 2, set it to zero again. Variables declared as Static preserve their value after the subroutine ends.

Comment: Thank you for your response Steve Rindsberg. Just to clarify, you are talking about using a Select Case block instead of a If-ElseIf block correct?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to @SteveRindsberg. I figured it out and added Select Case to my toolbox. This is the code that I came up with. Works great.

```
Sub SwitchPlayers2()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim RGB As String

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)

       Select Case iLastRan
          Case Is = 0
                oSl.Shapes("T1NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2NB", "T3NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2+1G", "T2-1G", "T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = True
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G")).Visible = False
                iLastRan = iLastRan + 1
            Case Is = 1
                oSl.Shapes("T2NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1NB", "T3NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G", "T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = True
                oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T2+1G", "T2-1G")).Visible = False
                iLastRan = iLastRan + 1
            Case Is = 2
                 oSl.Shapes("T3NB").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
                 oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1NB", "T2NB")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
                 oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T1+1G", "T1-1G", "T2+1G", "T2-1G")).Visible = True
                 oSl.Shapes.Range(Array("T3+1G", "T3-1G")).Visible = False
                 iLastRan = iLastRan + 1
                     If iLastRan > 2 Then
                         iLastRan = 0
                     End If
        End Select

    End Sub
```